# Modifying Element with Index in Python

Tags: python, indexing, sequence

I am a beginner in Python. I am learning currently how to Modify an element with index

MyCode:

```
data = [4, 6, 8]
for index, value in enumerate(data):
    data[index] = data[index] + 1
    value = value * 2


print(data)
print(value)
```

Terminal Output:

```
[5, 7, 9]
16
```

Terminal Output Expectation:

```
[5, 7, 9]
[8, 12, 16]
```

Why didn’t I get my expected output? Now I have tried to define an  empty_list before my FOR loop and then add the VALUE variable to it, then print(the_empty_list)

Here:

```
data = [4, 6, 8]
empty_list = []
for index, value in enumerate(data):
    data[index] = data[index] + 1
    value = value * 2
    **(How to add VALUE to the empty_list)**

print(data)
print(empty_list)
```

** **I am finding the asterisked part difficult. Who knows what I should do here?

Comment: `empty_list.append(value)`?

Comment: Your `value` variable references each value from `data` in turn. It ends up referencing the last value, ie `8`, which you then multiply by 2, so `value` ends up being `16`.

Comment: I have a question... why doesn't "value" disappear after its scope ends?

Comment: Ok, so this is a good question from a python beginner. They posted their *exact* code, and showed its full output, plus their expected output. They then went half way to trying for some code which might work. Well done. +1

Comment: @FLAK-ZOSO: the `for` block does not start a separate scope. (neither does `if`, nor `while`). Its only modules, functions and classes which introduce scopes.

Comment: Why were you expecting `value` to be a list?

Comment: It looks like you've already successfully modified the elements of the list using their index. Your question seems to be more about appending items to a list. If that is indeed the case, please [edit] your title to reflect your actual question. Otherwise this is a very well-asked question. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your list is empty you can't access it with an index. Use [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) method to add new elements:

```
data = [4, 6, 8]
empty_list = []
for index, value in enumerate(data):
    data[index] = data[index] + 1
    value = value * 2
    empty_list.append(value)

print(data)
print(empty_list)
```

Output:

```
[5, 7, 9]
[8, 12, 16]
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you @Corralien very much. You made it easy